# How to access image elements inside an SVG with jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom, svg

I have an SVG file which contains elements I'd like to manipulate with jQuery. Is this possible? I can access the SVG tag okay, but not the elements inside.

```
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" style="max-height:400px;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 485 480">
<image width="678" height="678" transform="translate(-94 -100)" id="section1" class="lime" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,......">
</svg>
```

I'd like to be able to access either **#section1** or **.lime**, but currently can only get as far as **Layer_1**. Later in the code there's a click function which changes the content of a tab, and this works if I change the trigger element to **Layer_1**

Bonus question - is there a way to pull in the data for the Base64 image as that would make the code a lot tidier?

Thanks!

Comment: Any thoughts at all..?

Comment: Create a [mcve]. It is very hard to debug imaginary code.